# getting a Compilation error during npm run build

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint, npm-build

On executing the `npm run build` command I'm getting the following error

> ```
> C:\Users\syedk\cutQ\cutq-app>npm run build
>
> > cutq-app@0.1.0 build C:\Users\syedk\cutQ\cutq-app
> > react-scripts build
>
> Creating an optimized production build...
> Failed to compile.
>
> src\components\Dialog\index.js
>  Line 20:3:  Definition for rule 'no-' was not found  no-
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
>
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! cutq-app@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the cutq-app@0.1.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\syedk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-14T12_45_37_060Z-debug.log
> ```

At given line I dont see any issue what could be the problem??

```
  const renderIconButton = (handleClose) => { //line where error is indicated
    return (
      <div className={classes.iconButtonWrapper}>
        <IconButton onClick={(e) => handleClose(e)}>
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    );
  };
```